# Add an object to WPF Combo box Items collection, but only show specific property to the client

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

If I have a class like:

```
public class Product
{
     public int ProductId { get; set; }

     public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a collection of Products (stored in products variable)

```
 foreach (var product in products)
 {
     ProductComboBox.Items.Add(product.ProductName);
 }
```

This adds product names to combo box, but only that. Is there a way to do something like this:

```
 foreach (var product in products)
     {
         ProductComboBox.Items.Add(product);
     }
```

But when combo box is opened, only show product names (but store the entire product object in the combo box?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the `DisplayMember` property ? 

`ProductComboBox.Items.Add(product);ProductComboBox.DisplayMember = product.ProductName;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DisplayMemberPath property to do this.

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="ProductName"/>
```